# Postgres identical JSONB records not evaluating as equal

Tags: c#, python, postgresql, psycopg2, npgsql

I have a JSONB column that stores two-dimensional float arrays.

```
{"field1": [[0.04735202492211838,0.48957828405235093 [0.42866042256355286,0.5729520320892334]], "field2": [[etc.],[etc.]]}
```

The fields(keys) always have the same name, the arrays(values) are always [2][2].

The issue: Say I insert the above JSON into my JSONB column using Npgsql and Newtonsoft.JSON as follows:

```
using Npgsql;
using NpgsqlTypes;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
...
conn = new NpgsqlConnection(...);
conn.Open();
template = new Dictionary<string, double[,]>();

// Not sure if this assignment actually conforms, just illustrative
template["field1"] = [[0.04735202492211838,0.48957828405235093],[0.42866042256355286,0.5729520320892334]]
template["field2"] = [[etc.],[etc.]] //not actual values of course

using (var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("UPDATE JSONBTABLE SET JSONB_COL = @j WHERE JSONB_ID = @c", conn))
{
    // Could it be an encoding issue with the string?
    // doesn't makes sense, given impl of JSONB
    string js = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(template);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("j", NpgsqlDbType.Jsonb, js);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("c", 1);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

This updates the values as expected, nothing seemingly wrong.

If I then query like the following in Python, the issue becomes apparent

```
import psycopg2
from psycopg2.extras import Json
...
conn = psycopg2.connect(...)
cur = conn.cursor()

# for this example, our JSONBTABLE only has the record with the one column
cur.execute(
    """
    SELECT JSONB_COL
    FROM JSONBTABLE
    WHERE JSONB_ID = %s
    """, (1,)
)

cols = {column.name: i for i, column in enumerate(cur.description)}
row = cur.fetchone()

jsonb_dict = row[cols["JSONB_COL"]]

#jsonb_dict["field1"] == [[0.04735202492211838,0.48957828405235093],[0.42866042256355286,0.5729520320892334]]
#jsonb_dict["field2"] == [[etc.],[etc.]]

# Assuming that the JSONBTABLE has a column JSONB_ID as PK
cur.execute(
    """
    SELECT JSONB_ID
    FROM JSONBTABLE
    WHERE JSONB_COL = %s
    """, (Json(jsonb_dict),)
)

# This returns nothing. No match. Nada
cur.fetchone()
```

If I now insert the JSONB into the table in Python, then query as above, `cur.fetchone()` will return id of `2`, matching the OCRB_ID of the duplicate inserted in the python code. Example of insert follows:

```
cur.execute(
    """
    INSERT INTO JSONBTABLE(JSONB_COL)
    VALUES(%s)
    """, (Json(jsonb_dict),)
)
conn.commit()
```

Looking at the results of the table visually, as `SELECT JSONB_COL FROM JSONBTABLE` after inserting an exact duplicate in python code, they are identical.

But Postgres doesn't find them identical because the following returns `FALSE`

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT JSONB_COL FROM JSONBTABLE where JSONB_ID = 1) = 
  (SELECT JSONB_COL FROM JSONBTABLE where JSONB_ID = 2);
```

even stranger, this returns `TRUE`:

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT JSONB_COL->'field1' FROM JSONBTABLE where JSONB_ID = 1) = 
  (SELECT JSONB_COL->'field1' FROM JSONBTABLE where JSONB_ID = 2);
```

but this returns `FALSE`:

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT JSONB_COL->'field2' FROM JSONBTABLE where JSONB_ID = 1) = 
  (SELECT JSONB_COL->'field2' FROM JSONBTABLE where JSONB_ID = 2);
```

Again, visually, all fields of the entire JSONB record for `JSONB_ID = 1` and `JSONB_ID = 2` are identical. I've visually inspected them, character for character.

Comment: if you want help. build reproducible env. eg at db-fiddle. with your data sample. otherwise analyzing your queries with no idea what JSONB_ID = 1 is and JSONB_ID = 2 is makes no sense.

Comment: I know this isn't helpful at all, but obviously `field2` is somehow different between the two rows, whereas `field1` isn't (it so happens that you've omitted the contents of `field2` in your sample). I'd examine again, digit by digit, that they're identical, it's probably a case of Json.NET and Python not serializing those floating point values in exactly the same way.

Comment: @ShayRojansky, it turned out to be that, but complicated by PgAdmin. Apparently PgAdmin has a reputation for rounding values, so I could not see the difference between the two records, since pgAdmin rounded them identically. In actuality, C#'s floats had a higher precision than Python's. I would have discovered the issue much faster if PgAdmin hadn't done its rounding, so if anyone wants to address that in an answer I'd accept it

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question to close it out if you want to do that :) @DocML